# Does XSLT have to include the attribute prefix?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

My source XML has attributes with a "wd:" prefix like this

```
<wd:EMPLID>1234</wd:EMPLID>  
<wd:First_Name>Jack</wd:First_Name>
```

When I write my XSLT is there a way I can say

`<xsl:value-of select="EMPLID"/>`

instead of

`<xsl:value-of select="wd:EMPLID"/>`

The goal is to make the code easier to read.

Comment: I don't believe so, no. The namespaces are considered to be part of the tag. You might be able to get away with using the wildcard '*', but that may not be worth it, depending on the file.

Comment: Those aren't attributes, they are elements.

Answer (score 2):

> When I write my XSLT is there a way I can say
>
> ```
> <xsl:value-of select="EMPLID"/>
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```
> <xsl:value-of select="wd:EMPLID"/>
> ```

In the first place, it is important to understand that it is not the specific prefix that is important, but the namespace URI to which the prefix is bound. The source document and stylesheet can use different prefixes to designate the same namespace URI.

In the second place, XPath, and therefore XSLT, evaluate name tests against "expanded names", which are (namespace URI, name) pairs, so you *do* somehow have to specify the namespace, if any, to which each name belongs.  The namespace prefix bindings in effect for an XPath expression in an XSLT element's attribute are those that are in scope on that XSLT element.  However, any default namespace applicable in that scope *does not* apply to such an XPath expression.

If you're using XSLT 1.0, then that's pretty much that.  The language provides no mechanism for specifying a non-empty default namespace in which to interpret unprefixed names appearing in XPath expressions.  Possibly your implementation has an extension providing that, but relying on such an extension is not portable.

If you're using XSLT 2.0 or later, however, then there is a specific provision for what you want to do, as already given by another answer.  The `xpath-default-namespace` attribute of the element carrying the XPath expression, if it has one, or that of the innermost containing element that has one, if any, specifies the namespace URI with which to interpret unprefixed names in the expression.  You could specify that at the stylesheet  level, on the `xsl:value-of` element(s), or on any element between.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the attribute `xpath-default-namespace` can be used for this purpose.

See: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#unprefixed-qnames

> The attribute [xsl:]xpath-default-namespace (see 3.5 Standard Attributes) may be used on an element in the stylesheet to define the namespace that will be used for an unprefixed element name or type name within an XPath expression

For example, it can be used on the `stylesheet` element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xpath-default-namespace="http://www.example.com/wd"  
                                 <!-- ^ replace with namespace uri-->
 >
```

Comment: But we ought to point out that this feature requires XSLT 2.0, and those (like the OP) who are not XML experts usually pick the first thing that comes to hand which tends to be XSLT 1.0.